# jquery inserting html doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, insert, html-table

I have got a table where i want to insert html in a td on the next row.
I pasted one row below.

```
<tr class="content">
    <td align="center">
      <a class="version" href="theurl">click here to update the td in the row below</a>
    </td>
    <td align="left">col 2</td>
    <td align="left">col 3</td>
    <td align="left">col 4</td>
    <td align="left">col 5</td>
    <td align="left">col 6</td>
</tr>
<tr class="version" style="display: none;">
    <td colspan="6"></td>  <-- this is where i want to insert the new html in.
</tr>
```

my jquery script looks like this.

```
$("a.version").click(function () {
    var sLink = $(this).attr("href"); <-- this gets the link to retrieve data from
    var nexttr = $(this).parent().parent().next(".version"); <-- gets the next tr
    var nexttrtd = $(this).parent().parent().next(".version td:first"); <-- gets the first td in the next tr. alerting the colspan displays 6 (which is correct)

    nexttrtd.html("hello world"); <-- this wont insert the text in the td.
    nexttr.css("display", "");

    return false;
});
```

Now the question is, why doesn't the html get shown in the td? I have tried append, innerHTML = "bla" and that won't work either.

Think i'm doing things according the manual, but can't really figure out where it goes wrong.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `next()` probably fails as it tries to find a `td:first` element that's next to the current `tr`. Try this instead:

```
$("a.version").click(function () {
    var sLink = $(this).attr("href"); <-- this gets the link to retrieve data from

    var nexttrtd = $(this).closest('tr').next('.version').find('td:first');
    nexttrtd.html("hello world"); // This will insert "hello world" to the td

    return false;
});
```

I've reduced some redundant code that didn't seem to do anything. The weird thing is that you selected `nexttr` but then did the search for `nexttrtd` all over again from the start. You could have just used the `nexttr` element in aid:

```
var nexttr = $(this).closest('tr').next(".version"); // gets the next tr
var nexttrtd = nexttr.find('td:first'); // Gets the first td in that row
```

Comment: don't forget `nexttr.show();` after "hello world" get put in the td

Comment: Thanks! i put in the redundant code to make sure i got the right element. but chaining nexttr with .find maked it all work.
it also fixed the second problem i wrote about (.html)

Answer (score 2):

> html doesn't insert the sData string IN the but IN STEAD OF the .

Use .append(), not .html()!

Comment: yepp that worked, but only after i appended it to the element found with nexttr.find("td:first") in the original code the code would get inserted next to the <td> when using append.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: To future users that see this, append will only add new info to object, if you need to reset, than use html();

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works for me. Is jQuery included properly in your page header, without any typo? I tested it with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your jQuery script is executed on the page.  If it's not, the click event will never be added for your a tag.

Answer (score 0):

got one part working now. key to get the td in the next tr was the following:

var nexttrtd = $(this).parent().parent().next("tr.version, td");
  $.get(sLink, function(sData){
   nexttrtd.html(""+sData+"");
   nexttr.css("display", "");
  });

(a comma in "tr.version, td") The thing now is that html doesn't insert the sData string IN the  but IN STEAD OF the .

That's why i went around that by inserting " too but surely this isn't the way it should be or what?

Is there a proper way to do this?

(appending the sData will but the sData next to the  so that is not wanted either.